# Component is declared but never used

Tags: reactjs

I keep getting this weird message and React isn´t rendering my component. I am pretty sure I am rendering and importing it correctly:

Container:

```
import searchBar from "./searchBar";

class ItemList extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
      <searchBar/>
        );
    }
}
```

searchBar

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const searchBar = () => {
    return <div>ssuhsuhuhsususu</div>;
  }
export default searchBar
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change to

```
const SearchBar = () => {
  return <div>ssuhsuhuhsususu</div>;
}
export default SearchBar;
```

I you give name in small caps it will be considered as HTML tag such as 
      `<p>, <div>`
So your component should always be starting with CAPS.

Comment: In addition, as you are only declaring a stateless functional compoent, there is no need to import Component. So change import React, { Component } from 'react'; to import React from 'react';

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use component which name start with lowercase then use can use following tips:

Just assign it to capitalised variable before using it.

```
import searchBar from "./searchBar";
const Foo = searchBar;
<Foo/>
```

**Full Code:**

```
import searchBar from "./searchBar";

const Foo = searchBar;

class ItemList extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
        <Foo/>
        );
    }
}
```